# How to save state of my android app after closing?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've been working on an app lately and didnt figure out how to save the state of my application after closing ,i found something about SharedPreferences but i saw that it saves a (key,value) ,it can help if i want to store the username and the password but how to store the whole state of the app ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-on-android). It has exactly what you need. Just override `onSaveInstanceState` and save whatever custom values you may have to the bundle, and retrieve it by overriding `onRestoreInstanceState`.